# Electron + React: SVG Loading Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, electron, electron-builder

I have an issue with my react-application when I build it with electron-builder.

I just want to show an application logo with either dark or light font-colour depending on the currently selected theme. For that, I created 2 separate SVG's (dark and light).

**The problem**

- If I start the react-app with `react-scripts` and `electron .`, my SVG Icon gets rendered (everything works as expected).
- If I create a full electron build of the react-app and afterwards start the build, the icon only appears **for the first render**.
- If the screen gets rerendered, the SVG image is not visible.

I also looked into the dev-inspector of electron and the `src` property for the image is exactly the same as for the first render.

The imports of my 2 logos:

```
import LightLogo from "./images/lightLogo.svg"
import DarkLogo from "./images/darkLogo.svg"
```

The `img` component:

```
<img
     className={styles.logo}
     src={props.theme === Themes.DARK.name ? LightLogo : DarkLogo}
     width={"40%"}
     alt={"Logo"}
/>
```

The tag in the compiled app:

```
<img class="jss742" src="./static/media/darkLogo.667e0ffc.svg" width="40%" alt="Logo">
```

[Logo not working after second render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwE7P.png)

[Unpackaged app.asar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrTb0.png)

This is my first question, so if you need any further information, feel free to ask.
Thanks

Comment: For the development mode, this SVG will be renderer correctly

Comment: But in production mode, there isn't the SVG file in the right location

Comment: As you can see, after build your app is running at win-unpacked folder but there is not static folder in win-unpacked folder

Comment: Try to change "./statc/...." to "./resource/destfolder/build/static/..."

Comment: Following up on this, was there any resolution @Eternity. I have run across this issue as well, first render it works great and images show up fine, second render the images are gone. Seems to be both svg and png files. Some png files always render, others never  render.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by adding `<base href="./" />` to my index.html file.